# How we can open browser through j2me code in ubuntu os?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-me

How we can open browser through Java ME code in ubuntu os ?

I am using the below given code

```
String URL1="any url";
midlet.platformRequest(URL1);
```

The above line does not open the browser in the UBUNTU 10.10 but its working fine on windows os.

Please help me if any body else have faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use emulator (which one?), check if it is properly configured (emulators tend to have stuff like that in User Guide y'know)

- eg [this article](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/platformRequest/) provides a recipe for WTK / ME SDK:

> ...The J2ME Wireless Toolkit supports the `platformRequest()` method, but
>   before using the method you must tell the toolkit what to do when it's
>   invoked. You can associate only one platform service with
>   `platformRequest()`. For instance, if for testing purposes you associate
>   the method with your browser, the browser will be launched every time
>   you call `platformRequest()`. If you need more flexibility, you can
>   associate `platformRequest()`  with a script that will use the URL
>   scheme to route the request to the right handler.
>
> To associate a particular platform service with `platformRequest()`,
>   simply add a `com.sun.midp.midlet.platformRequestCommand` attribute to
>   the `system.config` file in the toolkit's lib directory. For example, to
>   invoke the Mozilla browser whenever `platformRequest()` is called, add
>   the following to `system.config`:
>
> ```
> # Associate the Mozilla browser with platformRequest() - Windows
> com.sun.midp.midlet.platformRequestCommand: "C:\Program Files\mozilla.org\Mozilla\mozilla.exe"
> ```
>
> Given this setting, the call
>   `platformRequest("http://developers.sun.com/mobility")` will launch
>   Mozilla, and the browser will navigate to Sun's developer mobility
>   portal...